# Stripe - Sending money to credit card/bank

Tags: php, stripe-payments

As far as I understand, regarding the Stripe transfers, you are able to send money to a credit card / bank account, even if those isn't registered with Stripe.

Following their API, I've come up with below code to send money to a credit card:

```
$amount = inputFilter($_POST['amount']);
$amount = $amount*100;
$destination = "card_6WWSXFfQsZEc66"; //Card data is a test card            

#$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($userdata["stripe_id"]);
$transfer = \Stripe\Transfer::create(array(
    "amount" => $amount,
    "destination" => $destination,
    "description" => "test payment"
));

$event_id = $tranfer->id;
$event = \Stripe\Event::retrieve($event_id);

die($event);
```

The response I am getting from above PHP code is this:

> The card card_6WWSXFfQsZEc66 is not attached to this Stripe account.
>   External accounts can only be attached to standalone Stripe accounts
>   via the dashboard.

Have I misunderstood something? Aren't you supposed to be able to transfer funds from your own Stripe account to standalone bank/credit cards?

Comment: "external accounts can only be attached ... via the dashboard". So... did you attach this external credit card in the dashboard?

Comment: @MarcB But "attached" - what does that mean in this case?

Comment: Attached means added. You cannot add a card as a destination for standalone accounts only for managed accounts.

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I understand, regarding the Stripe transfers, you are able to send money to a credit card / bank account, even if those isn't registered with Stripe.

Actually, you cannot send money to a credit card or bank account if it is not linked to a connected account.

Comment: Is there any way around in stripe so that I can send money to cards?